# Does perceived peer acceptance have any significant influence on adult anti-social behavior?

Tags: psychology, sociology

This question was spawned as the result of a comment on [another question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7167/do-rapists-widely-believe-that-it-is-common-for-men-to-be-rapists)

> I am sure there are a number of jokes {about rape}! I am not so sure
>   that they are told so commonly to make any difference to the rapists
>   though. Also, there are a number of Jew jokes--possibly many more than
>   rape jokes. Does this make anti-Semites feel that it is socially
>   accepted to be racist or even that "everybody is a racist"?

Is there any evidence that these sorts of displays of at least quasi-acceptance of anti-social behaviors leads perpetrators to believe that their acts are acceptable and common?

Comment: Anecdotal evidence. See for example [this joke about jews](http://www.haaretz.com/jewish-world/news/james-jones-jewish-joke-funny-or-inappropriate-1.284851), retold on a Jewish newspaper. Also, think about African-Americans calling themselves via the N-word. Does this make *anybody* think it's OK to use that word?

Comment: @Sklivvz that phenomenon is called [reappropriation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reappropriation).

Comment: [Only a ginger...](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f0IVuGK7sAw)

Comment: @Chad: I've had to clean the comments in the other question. Remember that comments come and go easily so it's not wise to point to them elsewhere :-)